# Markers for Google maps not in right spot

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I have created a google map using the google maps for rails gem. I am using custom svg markers.

The markers are not appearing over the proper location (see Dallas or Chicago in attached image).

In my controller I have created a hash object. I have tried to adjust the marker's position with the marker_anchor property, but it doesn't appear to have any effect on the position of the image on the map. I also tried using the int 1-9 format or richmarker (ie [1, true]) but this did not work either.

```
@hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@cities_for_map) do |city, marker|
  marker.lat city.latitude
  marker.lng city.longitude
  marker.picture({
    "url" => "/images/maps/regular.marker.svg",
    "width" => 13,
    "height" => 13,
    "marker_anchor" => [0, 50]
  })
  marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/destinations/map_tile.html", :locals => { :city => city})
end
```

Am I trying to modify the wrong property or is their a bug with the gem?

[image]

Comment: seems you move marker 50px up (your anchor), so yes all markers have offset

Comment: hey @apneadiving the map in the image was actually [0,0]. [0,50] didn't do anything different to the placement.

Comment: ok do you use the latest version?

Comment: Currently using 'gmaps4rails', '~> 2.1.2'

Comment: ok... what about your raw data? btw, use `anchor`, not `marker_anchor`, see code: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/gmaps/google/builders/marker.coffee#L12

Comment: The data is dead on. Anchor worked, every time the map zoomed up or down, marker would move some where new.

Comment: mm, I dont believe in ghosts, please paste your raw data in a gist or a plunkr so we can have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@apneadiving solved this

Use need to use anchor, not marker_anchor. I assumed that I was using the richmarker library out of the box.